# InvalidOperationException: The entity type 'x' requires a primary key to be defined. If you intended to use a keyless entity type call 'HasNoKey()'

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Not sure why I get this error even though I have the "Key" attribute on the key column. Class looks like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    [Key]
    private string MyPrimaryKey { get; set; } 

    ...
}
```

Comment: You have to define `MyPrimaryKey` as `public`

Comment: ah of course, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please define the `MyPrimaryKey` as `public`.

```
public class MyClass
{
    [Key]
    public string MyPrimaryKey { get; set; } 

    ...
}
```